# Button click does not work in Celltemplate angular grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I m trying to work with celltemplate. But click event did not work.

```
    $scope.format = function(val){
            return val.replace(/\//g, "");
        };

        var executionColumns = {
            data: [],
            enableSorting: true,
            paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
            paginationPageSize: 25,
            enableColumnMenu: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            columnDefs: [

              { field: 'StartDate', cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="format (row.entity)">log</button>' },
              { field: 'Status' },

            ]

        };
```

So what should I do? What is the wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me like the 2nd code

```
         columnDefs: [
          { field: 'StartDate', cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="format(grid.getCellVale(row.entity)   )">log</button>' },
          { field: 'Status' },

        ]
```

or move your format function to an externalscope defined as

```
 $scope.globalExternalScope = {
       format:function(entity){..........}
    }
```

and then use the template like

```
         columnDefs: [
          { field: 'StartDate', cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="getExternalScopes().format(grid.getCellVale(row.entity)   )">log</button>' },
          { field: 'Status' },

        ]
```

Comment: I read 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/099_upgrading_from_2 and I ediğt my code like below and worked. Intersting:

'<button  type="button" class="btn-small" ng-click="grid.appScope.format (row.entity)">log</button>'

Answer (score 0):

Use 
   `<button ng-click="grid.appScope.format (row.entity)">log</button>`

it is working for me now!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `.component` inside of which you render a `ui-grid` and your method is defined as:

`this.handleClick = function(){...}`

It will be available to you in `cellTemplate` via 

`cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="grid.appScope.$ctrl.handleClick()">log</button>' }`