# Row template 'grid.appScope.functionname()' not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid, based on mouse hover of user on a particular row, i need to show the button in a cell of that particular row. I tried with row template, in which i will call a method using 'grid.appScope,functionname()'. But its not working. Below us my code.
1.GridOptions:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    headerTemplate: '/SourceHtml/Templates/HomeHeaderTemplate.html',
    rowTemplate: rowTemplate(),
    data: 'glues',
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    columnDefs:
          [{ field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: false },
          { field: 'Brand', displayName: 'Brand', enableCellEditOnFocus: true },
          { field: 'Quarter', displayName: 'Quarter', enableCellEditOnFocus: true },
          { field: 'Modified', displayName: 'Modified', enableCellEditOnFocus: true },
          { name: 'report', displayName: 'report', cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"><span>Reports</span></span></button> ' },
          { name: 'edit', displayName: 'Edit', cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtnDdl" type="button" class="btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"><span>Edit</span></span></button> ' }]
};
```

2.GridData:

```
$scope.glues = [{ Name: 'Bob', Brand: 'CEO', Quarter: '2015 Q1', Modified: 'Alexander' },
          { Name: 'Bob', Brand: 'CEO', Quarter: '2015 Q1', Modified: 'Alexander' }];
```

3.RowTemplate:

```
function rowTemplate() {
    return $timeout(function () {
        alert("hi");
        return '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.fnOne(row)" ng-mouseover="grid.appScope.fnOne(row)"  ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ui-grid-cell></div>';
    }, 6000);
}
```

4.Method called from rowTemplate:

```
$scope.fnOne = function (entity) {
    alert(row);
};
```

My plan is to call the fnOne() method from rowTemplate and from there to use ng-class="{hideByDefault:!inputs}", where hideByDefault display will be none and to set inputs to true in fnOne method. But fnOne method is not getting called.

Please suggest any ideas. Any other type of implementing also welcomed.

Comment: can you try the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28556566/4260544

Comment: Why $timeout is used in rowTemplate function? Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: RowTemplate was called when the controller got loaded so i thought that may be one of the reason for not calling appScope method and added it. But its of no effect.

Comment: @prathamgn hi, any updates, grid.appScope is not working for me, I am using getExternalScopes()..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, in our application we decided to go with Angular Smart Table instead of Angular ui grid. On doing some POCs we were able to achieve some of the things easily in Smart Table that were complex in Angular ui grid.